# Getting the Span id attribute Value in Jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have a "mytable" which contains "mytd"  inturn  contains the "Myspan" i want to get the 
.I want to get the "myspan_1" in jquery .How do i do that.

Small try here

```
$("#mytable").find('td > #span').attr("value","myspan_+i");
```

where "i" is an incrementing value

I coud not get Span id .All iam trying "id" value of span tag

Comment: It is difficult to tell what you want. It would be helpful if you posted part of the HTML. Do you want to *get* or *set* the ID of each span. Is there one span per `<tr>`? per `<td>`?

Comment: I want to get the id of each Span .If the Span is "myspan_1" or "myspan_2" i want to get the 1 and 2 value

Comment: Ok, but how many spans are there that have an ID? Do you want the number from every single one? How do you want it? In an array? Providing your HTML would be very helpful. It would answer a lot of questions.

Comment: @Patrick- There are many spans for each Row .But i want the just Incremented value  or i want the value just i(myspan_i).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try these

```
$("#mytable").find("td > span").attr("id");
```

this will get the `id` of the current span. if you want to assign an `id` to the span you can do this.

```
$("#mytable").find("td > span").attr("id", "myspan_"+i");
```

where `i` is an incremental variable.

furthermore, if you are adding id to each `td > span` you can do a for loop or `$.each()` in all td of `#mytable`

```
var i=0;
$.each($("#mytable").find("td"), function(){
    $(this).find("span").attr("id", "myspan_"+i);
    i++;
});
```

#### Edit:

As I read your title i think I miss understood your question.  But I think here's what you want.  You want to get the value of the attribute `Value` in the element with id of `#span` actually if you are looking for an `id` in jquery, you can call it directly since `id` is always unique.

```
$("#span").attr("value", "myspan_"+i);
```

since `i` is an incremental value, you need to put it outside the quotes.

#### Edit 2:

To add value to an attribute `value`

```
$("#mytable").find("td > #span").attr("value", "myspan_"+i);
```

#### Edit 3:

Assuming your `span id` has an incremental `myspan_1` which always starts at 1

```
var spanid = $("#mytable").find("td > span").attr("id", "myspan_"+i);
var idvalue = spanid.split('_')[1];
```

this will get the 1 of the myspan_1

or you could just directly get the `i` since `i` is the number that you want

```
var spanid = $("#mytable").find("td > span").attr("id", "myspan_"+i);
var idvalue = i;
```

Comment: I think the last quote in the second example needs to go (as in your 3rd example), i.e. ("id", "myspan_"+i);

Comment: Thanks a lot The first one worked out .So Iam Getting the Value  "myspan_1" .where "1" is the Incremented value and i want to get the just incremented Value  "1" or "2" .How do i do that

Comment: @AskSomeone, is my edit what you are trying to ask for? I'm somewhat confused a little bit.

Comment: Iam Getting the <span id> .Now i want only the Incremented Value 1 or 2 or 3