# How to get an the text value of an element in jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I have an HTML table generated dynamically with field names generated for each row  dynamically as well.

Here is the structure I have within the table. I have a `<td>` tag and within it I have a `<span>` tag. I want to get the value for each tag. I have tried this this way:

```
$("#txtname").attr('value',$("#table1").find('td > #selname_'+i).text());
```

In the above code I am setting the `$("#txtname")` (textbox value) with the value from the `<span>` tag (selname). Here `i` is an incrementing value.

I want to get the text, but do not get the `<span>` value, and I am not able to assign to it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3331580/getting-the-span-id-attribute-value-in-jquery

Comment: Please do not re-post questions. Instead, edit your original question if you have additions or clarifications. Re-posting wastes your time and ours.

Answer (score 1):

No need to make your selectors so complicated:

```
$("#txtname").val($("#selname_"+i).text());
```